# Change texts of tweets in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that changes the text of tweets
I retrieve and change the tweet text in a .js file with

```
var tweets = document.getElementsByClassName('js-tweet-text tweet-text');
for (var i = 0, l = tweets.length; i < l; i++) {
    tweets[i].innerText = 'Some text';
}
```

The tweets that are loaded when the page loads are changed to 'Some text' but when I scroll down the new tweets that are loaded do not change.
How can I change the new tweets text?

Edit:
I tried adding a timer:

```
var tweets = document.getElementsByClassName('js-tweet-text tweet-text');
var timer = setInterval(changeTexts, 1000);

function changeTexts() {
for (var i = 0, l = tweets.length; i < l; i++) {
    tweets[i].innerText = 'Some Text';
}
}
```

But that loads all the tweets on the html and I would like just to modify the new ones instead of modifying the ones already modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luke, use the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
var root = document.querySelector('#fTweets'),
    tweetBody = document.querySelector('#fTweetBody'),
    sendBtn = document.querySelector('#fSendBtn'),
    
    pushTweet = _ => root.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class='fTweet'>${tweetBody.value}</div>`);
sendBtn.addEventListener('click', e => pushTweet());

// This function changes the new tweet
let editTweet = e => e.innerHTML += '| Edited by me';

// Immediately after loading change downloaded tweets
// Do not forget about the availability of DOM
Array.from(root.children).forEach(e => editTweet(e));

// Create a MutationObserver instance
new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  // We process all the changes of the root node
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    // If this change units, then send a new node for processing
    // Note: There is no inspection, that to this example, but be sure to check what and where nodes are in real code
    if(mutation.type === 'childList'){
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach(item => editTweet(item));
    }
  });
}).observe(root, {childList: true});
```

```html
<div id='fTweets'><div class='fTweet'>First tweet...</div></div><hr />
<textarea placeholder='Your tweet...' id='fTweetBody'></textarea><br />
<input type='button' id='fSendBtn' value='Send' />
```